# Strange UITableView error: "Assertion Failure" on dequeuing static cells in storyboard

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode, swift, uitableview

I am getting this error:  *** Assertion failure in -[UITableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:forIndexPath:] with static cells.

My code is in Swift (the reuse identifiers are strings set as constants in the file):

`...
private let topTableViewCellIdentifier          = "topTableViewCell"
private let bottomTableViewCellIdentifier       = "bottomTableViewCell"
...`

```
    override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

    let reuseIdentifier = (indexPath.section == 0) ? topTableViewCellIdentifier : bottomTableViewCellIdentifier


    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier(reuseIdentifier, forIndexPath: indexPath)
    return cell
}
```

I have searched stack overflow for this error, and found a bunch of answers all basically saying the same thing: make sure the reuse identifier is the same as the one for the cell in the storyboard.

However, in my case, it is.

I have confirmed this repeatedly, and have cut and pasted from one to the other repeatedly in order to ensure this is the case.  Xcode clearly indicates that the correct value is being set.  I have cleaned.  I have even restarted.  I have done everything I can think of, and it does not see the cells in the storyboard.  They are set as static, and The correct class is being set in the inspector (though that should be clear by the fact that it gets the correct value)

[image]

Any thoughts or assistance would be appreciated.  I am using El Capitan and Xcode 7.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are attempting to use a static layout for a table view, you typically do not implement `tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath:`, the `UITableViewController` does this for you.  It is invalid to call the `dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:forIndexPath:` method for a statically configured `UITableView` (as the error indicates).

Comment: OK, apparently I needed more or less coffee, as this was one of the first things I tried, but did not seem to work.  I was going by various tutorials I have seen, as well as my apparently mis-learned lessons.  Yep.  This was the issue.  My cell contents were not appearing for other reasons and I simply went down the wrong rabbit hole.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure your UITableView is set to `Dynamic Prototypes`

[image]

Comment: Thanks, but this does not solve my problem, as I need the cells to be static.